# verification of difference of sets

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

New to this, would this be correct?

If we have $A = {1,2,3}, B = Z^{+}, C = [1,\infty)$

Where $C = {x \in R : x \geq} 1 $

Then $B-A $ would be:

$(x \in Z^{+}, x>3) $

and $C-A$ would be:

$(x \in R, x>3)$

Answer (score 1):

$C-A$ should include some elements that are less than $3$ as well. For example $1.5$ is in $C-A$. It has not been excluded.

$$C-A=(1, \infty) \setminus \{2,3\}=(1,2) \cup (2,3) \cup (3, \infty).$$

Comment: Thank you, was it typo the {2,3}. didn't you mean {1,2,3}

Comment: rather than $[1, \infty]$, I used $(1,\infty)$. I have removed the element $1$.